# Divide images into four equal images

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How to divide a set of images which (`512*512`) into four equal images; each is `256*256` and this repeated for `150` images ?

```
I = imread(['file',num2str(i),'.tif']);
I1 = I(1:size(I,1)/2,1:size(I,2)/2,:);
I2 = I(size(I,1)/2+1:size(I,1),1:size(I,2)/2,:);
I3 = I(1:size(I,1)/2,size(I,2)/2+1:size(I,2),:);
I4 = I(size(I,1)/2+1:size(I,1),size(I,2)/2+1:size(I,2),:);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have matlab at hand, so there might be some mistakes, but the idea will hold:

You have to choose how you will store your split up images. For example, you can use cells. I'll assume your images are called file1.tif, file2.tif and so on.

```
num_imgs = 150; %The total ammount of images you have
cropped_imgs = cell(1,num_imgs) %create empty 1 by 150 cell

%create a for loop to repeat over all images
for k in 1:num_imgs:
   I = imread(['file',num2str(k),'.tif']); %load your image
   sz = size(I,1)/2; %get half the size, assuming it's a square image
   %split images and pack into 1 by 4 cell
   cropped_imgs{k} = {I(1:sz, 1:sz), I(1:sz, sz+1:end), I(sz+1:end, 1:sz), I(sz+1:end, sz+1:end)}
end
```

Now you can access them by doing something like `cropped_imgs{127}{2}` for the second crop of image number 127. Hope this helps, but seriously, research a bit before posting a question. Maybe a better way to store the images would be in a 150 by 4 cell and access them by `cropped_imgs{127,2}`, but that depends on what you like.

EDIT: If you were asking how to split images in a less explicit way, you could try and use `imcrop` with a given rectangle and move the rectangle:

```
num_imgs = 150; %The total ammount of images you have
cropped_imgs = cell(4,num_imgs) %create empty 4 by 150 cell

%create a for loop to repeat over all images
for k in 1:num_imgs:
   I = imread(['file',num2str(k),'.tif']); %load your image
   sz = size(I)/2; %get half the size, assuming it's a square image
   %split images and pack into 1 by 4 cell
   cropped_imgs{k,1} = imcrop(I,[0,0,sz]);
   cropped_imgs{k,2} = imcrop(I,[sz(1),0,sz]);
   cropped_imgs{k,3} = imcrop(I,[0,sz(1),sz]);
   cropped_imgs{k,4} = imcrop(I,[sz,sz]);
end
```